# POM for my own repo is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: maven, netbeans, jitpack

I am currently learning software development and working on an assignment based on using a release from one project in another using jitpack.

The first project, which I want to add as a dependency in my second, simply has three classes and a JUnit test for each. I changed several things so I am at V5.0 release now.

https://github.com/MohamedMoustafaNUIG/assignment1/releases/tag/V5.0

My second project is not yet pushed, but this is the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nuig</groupId>
    <artifactId>assignment1_driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.MohamedMoustafaNUIG</groupId>
            <artifactId>assignment1</artifactId>
            <version>v5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

When I try to build with dependencies (in netbeans), I get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project assignment1_driver: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.nuig:assignment1_driver:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failure to find com.github.MohamedMoustafaNUIG:assignment1:jar:v5.0 in 
https://jitpack.io was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has 
elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I also get this warning:

```
The POM for com.github.MohamedMoustafaNUIG:assignment1:jar:v5.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Even though the zip file (from linked release) has the pom file.

Any help appreciated as I have no idea how to resolve this the issue

Answer (score 0):

You either need to:

- build `assignment1` on the *same machine* with `clean install` to make it available in the local repository.
- deploy `assignment1` to a Maven repository with `clean deploy` and then use this as a `<repository>`.